# How do I add a button to the subtitle of an MkMapView custom annotation?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton, mkmapview, mkannotation

Basically my program displays many annotations on a map. after the user clicks on one, It displays the title of the location. How can I add a button under the title that will display a new window with more information on the location? I would also be content with a button at the bottom of the screen that is greyed out until one location is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the viewForAnnotation method, set a button as the callout accessory view:

```
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
```

You can use rightCalloutAccessoryView or leftCalloutAccessoryView but the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW24) recommends putting a disclosure button on the right.

Respond to the button press in the [calloutAccessoryControlTapped](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW14) method.

Comment: I am new at this, so please forgive me when I ask where this viewForAnnotation method is exactly. I have three .h/.m files for the main view:
AnnotationView, Annotation, and MainViewController. which file should I place this under?

Comment: viewForAnnotation is a method you implement in the class that implements the MKMapViewDelegate protocol.  I assume for you this would be MainViewController.  I suggest looking at the Apple sample app MapCallouts.  In there, viewForAnnotation is implemented similarly to the example I gave (see MapViewController.m).  The documentation link in my answer has a link to MapCallouts or you can search apple.com for it.